# When to use "à" and "de" after adjective (e.g. impossible, difficile)?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I found the following sentences:

> Il est impossible de penser à cela.
>
> Difficile à dire.
>
> C'est difficile de choisir.
>
> Ces choses sont impossibles à comprendre.

These sentences are not coherent on the proposition of the adjectives, namely *à* and *de*.

But I don't understand when to use *à* and when to use *de*. How can I use them apart correctly?

Answer (score 0):

After an adjective, you can use *à* when this adjective is related to some kind of ability, attitude, or imminent action.

*De* is used to express feelings, stats of mind, and obligation.

You can see my source and some eg. in the following link: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/adjectives-with-prepositions/